# Apexcharts not working after installed to an existing React project

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to install Apexcharts to my existing React project then I'm following the official document but it doesn't work, but when I'm trying to create-react-app a new app and install it then it works.....Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Who is Apexcharts? What have you tried and what is not working? Share the detail steps with specific commands you tried. It’s difficult to guess and help you by just looking at the theatrical question you posted

Comment: Apexcharts is data visualization library and i tried to integrate it into my existing project.